How to remove outline
Can anyone say how to remove this outline? outline-color is doing nothing. If I use outline: none it becomes convex.
Example:

I tried to change the color of the outline, but no changes.


input {
  outline-style: auto;
  background-color: #363636;
  /* deactivated by editor
  position: absolute;
  left: 650px;
  bottom: 115px;
  */
}
<input>




outline: none is the way to remove it. What do you mean by it becomes convex?

Use your browser dev tools, and inspect the element to see what is actually going on. In Chrome at least, the outline is applied via :focus-visible { outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px; } and input:focus-visible { outline-offset: 0px; }, coming from the user agent stylesheet - so that is what you will have to explicitly overwrite.

Never remove CSS outlines

border :none;
just add this

Add both outline: none and border: none
And you will get the result you want


input {
    background-color: #363636;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: white;
 }
<input>




To change the color, size, and style of the outline. You should use the CSS property outline.
The outline property shorthand works like this:
outline:  width style color;
Also, the same border of the input color, size, and style can change:
border:  width style color;
Example Here:


input {
  border: none;
  background-color: #363636;
  outline: 2px solid red; 
}
<input />




Also, If you want to remove the outline use the CSS property as outline: none;.

outline-style: solid
outline-color: #fff
border: none

this does not address the outline. Border and outline are 2 completely different things

OP is talking about the outline which is normally visible when focusing the (input) element
